# Conditional probabilities of a chain of variables depending on one another

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Suppose there are $T$ variables $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_T\}$, and they have the following relationship
$$
p(x_t|x_{t-1}) = N \big( x_t; \sqrt{1-\beta_t}x_{t-1}, \beta_tI \big)
$$

that means there is a Gaussian distribution relationship between 2 adjacent variables. Then how to derive $p(x_t|x_1)$?

My question originates from the [DDPM paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11239.pdf), in which equation (2) and (4) state the distributions, I wonder how equation (4) is derived.

Comment: Eq (2) contains another multiplicative assumption.  Use that too and integrate out $x_{1:{t - 1}}$.

Comment: You only need to specify mean and variance, since the distribution remains Gaussian.

Comment: @Zhanxiong can you give more details please?

Comment: @avocado After applying the multiplicative assumption, a better way to circumventing explicit integration is following Xi'an's suggestion.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assumption (Eq (2) in the cited paper), the joint distribution of $X_1, \ldots, X_T$ given $X_0 = x_0$ (from now on, I will drop this conditioning qualifier for simplicity because it does not have impact on the derivation) is
\begin{align}
f(x_1, \ldots, x_T) = (2\pi)^{-T/2}(\beta_1\cdots\beta_T)^{-1/2}
\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{t = 1}^T\frac{1}{\beta_t}(x_t - \sqrt{\alpha_t}x_{t - 1})^2\right], \tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\alpha_t = 1 - \beta_t$ as in the cited paper. $(1)$ implies that the joint distribution of $(X_1, \ldots, X_T)$ is Gaussian
$^\dagger$. Hence the marginal distribution of $X_T$ is Gaussian, whence to determine the distribution of $X_T$, it suffices to determine its mean and variance.  By $X_t|X_{t - 1} = x_{t - 1} \sim N(\sqrt{\alpha_t}x_{t - 1}, \beta_t)$ for $t = 1, 2, \ldots, T$ and repeated application of the law of iterative expectations:
\begin{align}
E[X_T] = E[E[X_T|X_{T - 1}]] = \sqrt{\alpha_T}E[X_{T - 1}] = \cdots = \prod_{t = 1}^T\sqrt{\alpha_t}x_0.
\end{align}
Similarly, by the law of total variance:
\begin{align}
& \operatorname{Var}(X_T) = E[\operatorname{Var}(X_T|X_{T - 1})] + 
\operatorname{Var}(E[X_T|X_{T - 1}]) \\
=& E[\beta_T] + \operatorname{Var}(\sqrt{\alpha_T}X_{T - 1}) 
= \beta_{T} + \alpha_T\operatorname{Var}(X_{T - 1}).
\end{align}
Plugging in $\beta_T = 1 - \alpha_T$, this gives the recursive relation
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(X_T) - 1 = \alpha_T(\operatorname{Var}(X_{T - 1}) - 1),
\end{align}
which together with the initial condition $\operatorname{Var}(X_1) = \beta_1 
= 1 - \alpha_1$ yields
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(X_T) - 1 = \prod_{t = 2}^T\alpha_t(\operatorname{Var}(X_1) - 1) = -\prod_{t = 1}^T\alpha_t,
\end{align}
i.e., $\operatorname{Var}(X_T) = 1 - \prod\limits_{t = 1}^T\alpha_t$. This shows that $X_T|X_0 = x_0 \sim N(\sqrt{\bar{\alpha}_T}x_0, 1 - \bar{\alpha}_T)$.  The multivariate case can be derived analogously.

---

$^\dagger$ One way to see it is considering the following 1-to-1 non-singular affine transformation:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} 
Y_1 \\ Y_2 \\ \vdots \\ Y_T
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_1^{-1/2} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
-\beta_2^{-1/2}\sqrt{\alpha_2} & \beta_2^{-1/2} & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0      & 0      & \cdots & \beta_T^{-1/2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
X_1 \\ X_2 \\ \vdots \\ X_T
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix} 
-\beta_1^{-1/2}\sqrt{\alpha_1} \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} \tag{2}
\end{align}
By $(1)$ and $(2)$, the joint density of $(Y_1, \ldots, Y_T)$ is
\begin{align}
g(y_1, \ldots, y_T) = (2\pi)^{-T/2}\exp(-(y_1^2 + \cdots + y_T^2)/2),
\end{align}
which is clearly Gaussian.  Hence the joint distribution of $(X_1, \ldots, X_T)$ must be Gaussian too (as $(X_1, \ldots, X_T)$ is an affine transformation of $(Y_1, \ldots, Y_T)$ by $(2)$).

Comment: This is amazing, math is so beautiful. To make sense of your answer, I had to re-study a few things, such as why product of gaussian pdfs is still a gaussian, and why a subset of variables of multivariate gaussian still follows a gaussian distribution, law of total expecation and vairance etc.